# Does User Data Encryption App Require ECCN?

Tags: security, windows-8, cryptography, microsoft-metro

I am developing a Windows 8 Metro App which enables the User to encrypt their files such as Documents, Images and Songs. I use Key Length as 32 for AES Encryption. Does this app require ECCN? If Yes, What is the ECCN I can use to publish this app on the Windows 8 Store?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation

> If your app calls, supports, contains, or uses cryptography or encryption for any task that is not in the list of unrestricted tasks, it needs an Export Commodity Classification Number (ECCN) to be sold in the store.

[More about ECCN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Control_Classification_Number)

Here is the list of ECCN

[ALPHABETICAL INDEX TO THE COMMERCE CONTROL LIST](http://www.bis.doc.gov/policiesandregulations/ear/ccl_index.pdf)